# Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory' not found Laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, package, laravel-passport

Hello everyone i'm using **sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth** Based on laravel passport

- I'm getting this error

```
{message: "Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory' not found",…}
message: "Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\DiactorosFactory' not found"
exception: "Error"
file: "/app/vendor/smartins/passport-multiauth/src/Facades/ServerRequest.php"
line: 17
trace: [,…]
```

- This is my Composer

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.0",
    "smartins/passport-multiauth": "^6.0",
    "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "^2.0"
},
```

**NB: When i put this file (DiactorosFactory.php) in the directory from my older laravel project
it's work perfectly.**

Comment: having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in Readme.md: https://github.com/symfony/psr-http-message-bridge/blob/26068fa40d91305529cb168997c0b528bb6eef07/CHANGELOG.md

using DiactorosFactory is deprecated and was removed with version 2.0.0

```
Deprecated DiactorosFactory, use PsrHttpFactory instead
```

You will find a solution how to replace that in your code here:
https://github.com/sfelix-martins/passport-multiauth/pull/123/files#diff-b37981c79b4592847e664547ec085670454b57df4d701cd6218930b55169930fR17-R24

The official documentation how to use the new stuff you will find here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/psr7.html#usage

Comment: Those links can get broken in the future. Can you also add necessary information to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that package fixed the issue in their next version (7.0). If you upgrade to the newest version, that'll fix your issue.

If you can't upgrade that package, then your other option is to downgrade `symfony/psr-http-message-bridge` to version `^2.0`. This will also downgrade `laravel/passport` to version 8.4.0.